# CSS: relative position in dropdown menu affects parent

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a `li` parent that contains a `ul` child. Both need to be positioned as relative.

The problem is that the width of the `ul` child changes the width of the `li` parent.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<li class="nav open">
<ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
    <li id="t-smwbrowselink"><a href="/mediawiki/index.php/Special:Browse/Main_Page" rel="smw-browse" tabindex="-1">Browse properties</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li.nav.open {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    display:  inline-block;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
}
```

I add an image of the result. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1raT.png). How can I make the parent `ul` independent to the child if both are in relative position?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a snippet (best using http://jsbin.com) and demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using BootStrap? The sub menu / dropdown `ul` is `position: absolute` out of the box as you know.

You can add a `max-width` to the `li` in question - here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xu7u8prn/

```
li.dropdown.open {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

Please note I've gone ahead and got BootStrap default navigation code for my example.

You'll need to have an experiment with what exactly works in your case...

Comment: Hi David, thank you. Yeah that works. But then I should specify max-width to every item of my menu

Comment: @user3853854 scrap that last comment. The CSS class I've used will only target li's that have a sub menu (the classes "dropdown" and "open"). Remember to mark an answer as correct if helps you :-)

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. But if one item of my menu is for example  200px it wouldn't work. It should be dynamic

Comment: @user3853854 Then I'd suggest adding another class to those items: `<li class="dropdown big">` for example, then increasing the `max-width` to 200px or whatever you want for that class: `li.dropdown.open.big { max-width: 200px; }`... I'm not sure there is a "dynamic" way of achieving what you're looking for without something like JS.